# Can an IF statement be used inside math.max in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, nested

I want to know if it is possible to use an if statement inside of math.max.
For example if you have an object like so:

```
    public class Obj {
        private int i;
        private boolean b;
        public void setInt(int newInt) {
            this.i = newInt;
        }
        public void setBool(boolean newBool) {
            this.b = newBool;
        }
        public int getInt() {
            return this.i;
        }
        public boolean getIsTrue() {
            return this.b;
        }
    }
```

After initializing 2 new objects and defining all values, is it possible to do something like this:

```
    System.out.println(Math.max(if(obj1.getIsTrue()) {obj1.getInt()}, if (obj2.getIsTrue()) {obj2.getInt()}));
```

I know that it can be done with an array and a for loop, so I'm not asking is it possible at all, just is it possible to nest if statements in this way.

Comment: Or a ternary maybe? `obj1.getIsTrue() ? obj1.getInt() : 0`

Comment: Why don't you ask a compiler in the neighborhood?

Comment: this.b is a boolean, but newBool is int.  This.i (which else?) is int, but you declare to return a String. Same for getIsTrue. You can't imagine, how handy a compiler can be, for error detection! Go, get one!

Comment: I copied the code but forgot to change the variable type. It is corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `if` in Java is a *statement* and not an *expression*, and that means that it doesn't return a value. What you *can* use is a conditional expression (also known as the ternary operator), as long as you can provide a meaningful `else` part:

```
Math.max(obj1.getIsTrue() ? obj1.getInt() : 0, obj2.getIsTrue() ? obj2.getInt() : 0);
```

Also notice that `Math.max()` receives only 2 arguments, not 3 as you seem to expect.